# How to sort Excel Documents without opening a Collection in Blue Prism?

Tags: excel, blueprism

How to sort Excel Documents without opening a Collection in Blue Prism?
I am trying to find something new in BP, so maybe somebody knows how to do that?

Comment: Put detail in the filenames?

Comment: Do you mean sort the files in the explorer window or the appearance of those files when you look at the folder? Are you operating on a selection of excel files in a folder and need to pick them up based on some criteria?